# Trying to fix Dash script for platformer game

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to make a platformer game so I'm trying to make add a dash function into my script, but I keep geting this error over and over no mather what I do. Of course, I'm new to C# so I've just added a dash script into my player controller double jump animation script and I can't find anything online to help me. Please help! :(

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 16f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private bool doubleJump;

    private bool canDash = true;
    private bool isDashing;
    private float dashingPower = 24f;
    private float dashingTime = 0.2f;
    private float dashingCooldown = 1f;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (IsGrounded() && !Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            doubleJump = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if (IsGrounded() || doubleJump)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);

                doubleJump = !doubleJump;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (isDashing)
    {
        return;
    }

    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && canDash)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Dash());
    }

    Flip();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isDashing)
    {
        return;
    }

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
}

private IEnumerator Dash()
{
    canDash = false;
    isDashing = true;
    float originalGravity = rb.gravityScale;
    rb.gravityScale = 0f;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashingPower, 0f);
    tr.emitting = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
    tr.emitting = false;
    rb.gravityScale = originalGravity;
    isDashing = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
    canDash = true;
}
}
```

So I've been lookeing up stuff and trying anything I can for the last 2 hours and nothing is working so here we are -_-

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error is: Error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.